# NODEJS How do I perform an action when URL response status is 404?

Tags: node.js, url, discord.js, httpresponse, steam

I am making a discord bot and I want to make a command that sends 3 random characters and then puts those characters at the end of a url to check if it exists (in this case I am using steam accounts to check if the id is taken) but I need to make it so that when the response status is 404 it will send a message to say the ID is not taken.

```
var urlExists = require('url-exists');

      //3CHAR
   else if (message.content == "+3char") {     
     message.channel.send(getRandomString(3));


   var theURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/id/" + message.channel.lastmessage;

         urlExists("theURL");



      if (response.status != 404) {     
      return;

    }


    else {message.channel.send("`URL is not taken`");}


}
```

This is what I have right now, however I get the error 'response is not defined'.
Any suggestion would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your running into an `async` issue.  You need to pass in a callback function to `urlExists`.  The callback function executes once the `urlExists` object finishes executing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-exists

```
var urlExists = require('url-exists');

urlExists('https://www.google.com', function(err, exists) {
  console.log(exists); // true
});

urlExists('https://www.fakeurl.notreal', function(err, exists) {
  console.log(exists); // false
});
```

In your case, you'd want to do something along the lines of:

```
var urlExists = require('url-exists');

var theURL = "https://steamcommunity.com/id/" + message.channel.lastmessage;

urlExists("theURL", (err, exists) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  }

  if (exists) {
    message.channel.send("`URL is not taken`");
  } else {
    // do something when the URL does not exist
  }  
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify what this does is when the URL page is not found it will send a message, correct?